# Convert SVG path to SVG lines

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-path

I am trying to convert a disconnected path in SVG into SVG lines . 
e.g If I have drawn a triangle using

```
<path id="path" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
```

then after conversion , i should get 3 SVG lines

```
<line x1=150 y1=0 x2=75 y2=200/>
<line x1=75 y1=200 x2=225 y2=200 />
<line x1=225 y1=200 x2=150 y2=0 />
```

And this path can be disconnected that it can have multiple Moveto commands like

```
<path id="path" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 M450 200 L375 400 L525 400 Z" />
```

In this case I should get 6 SVG lines.
Also moveto and lineto commands may be absolute and relative
Any help ? 
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Robert Longson's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9103307/4235784) to [*"Turn SVG path into line segments"*](/q/9102563).

Comment: Thanks for the help altocumulus. I had already gone throught the link you provided. With some help from it , I wrote code to convert Path in Polyline.
Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fq9n7f76/18/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn SVG path into line segments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102563/turn-svg-path-into-line-segments)